# Ordering of data when summarizing with cube/grouping sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've got a simple query

```
select distinct m.STATE_CD, m.sex,SUM(c.cost) as TotalCost
    from members as m
    inner join claims as c on c.patid=m.PATID
    group by cube(m.STATE_CD,m.sex)
    order by m.STATE_CD
```

which returns a result set like

[image]

I would like to order by `STATE_CD` in the fashion that it is now, but is there a way to make the NULLS be at the bottom of the result set with the `STATE_CD` column still being in alphabetical order, without adding CASE statements to change the NULL to something that alphabetically falls last?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ISNULL in the order by:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (STATE CHAR(2));

INSERT @test (STATE)
SELECT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AK'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AL'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'AR';

/*Returns null first*/
SELECT * FROM @test ORDER BY STATE

/*Returns null last*/
SELECT * FROM @test ORDER BY ISNULL(STATE,'ZZ');
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

`ORDER BY CASE WHEN m.STATE_CD IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, m.STATE_CD`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use the cube grouping for hierarchical breakouts?  Generally I believe it lists the groupings out that become the nulls.  Can you just list 'group by with m.State, m.sex' and then list a predicate of 'where m.state is not null'.  Possible fix.

Other than that you are going to have to do something to define the nulls as a grouping I would guess.  Similar to isnull(m.State_CD, 'Totals') if you are sure all the nulls are representing totals from collection.  If you want to place them at the bottom but want to rename them later you could always rename them in a collection of a cte, temp table, nested select, etc.   And then relabel them later.